# How do I lubricate a sticky knob on an interior door?

Tags: doors, lubrication

## Problem

I have a door knob that does not turn as smoothly as it should.

I could replace it, but I'd rather try to repair it first.

The door knob in question is a basic interior door knob. There is no lock. It looks like this one:

[image]

## Questions

- Is it possible to lubricate the internals of the door knob hardware to return it to like new condition?
- What kind of lubricant is right for the job?
- Where should I apply the lubricant?

Comment: My first thought was, "you need a damp rag, not lubricant", then I realized that's not what you meant by "sticky". ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many times a "sticky" passage set like yours can be caused by slight mis-alignment of the knob parts with the internal mechanism.  Things shift over time (mostly droop, but that's a personal problem).

So pop of the cover plate, there's  a slot you stick a flat bladed screwdriver into (I think I see it at 2 o'clock), unscrew the knob and remove it.  Then lube up the mechanism from the inside as well as along the bolt on the outside.  Reassemble and screw down the 2 screw LOOSELY and try it, jiggle the knob if needed. It should operate freely. Snug the screws down a bit more, but not tight yet, try operating the knob again and if still running wild and free, tighten the screws fully and tap the cover plate back over the mounting plate.  (You did remember to put the cover plate on before reassembling, RIGHT?!)   It should operate much better now, if not, time for a trip to the hardware store.

OH and an LOL shout out to Freeman for a great comment, I thought the same thing!!!

Comment: Recommendations on lube type? I'm thinking "grease" of the general kind...

Comment: Product recommendations are frowned upon here, esp. shopping suggestions. But hopefully the moderators will allow this comment to persist.  First of all, grease is waaaay to thick, you need some sort of a light machine oil.   I recently found a product called SUPER SLICK SLICK STUFF.  It doesn't have the strong odor of WD-40, rather it's kinda a light citrus smell.  And it really is SUPER SLICK.  Works great.   Reminds me of Jeff Foxworthy's routine when he said, "I finally found a product that keeps the squirrels off the bird feeder". He was talking about different "personal" product, LOL.

Comment: I think "light lubricating oil" would be sufficiently non-product promoting as oppoesed to "grease".

Comment: @FreeMan  I think I said that before the product recommendation: " you need some sort of light machine oil".   Again, LOL on your first comment!

Answer (score 0):

Spray silicon lubricant in every opening you can find and work the knob.   (Try the easy fix first).